# MySQL merging table records with overlapping date spans

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a temporary table with overlapping booked dates. These dates can be overlapping in any combination of ways, as they are for multiple available rooms.

I would like to create a query that returns a consolidated set of dates. (The checkout date is an available day.)

For example, the following data

```
+--------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id     | rental_unit | checkin    | checkout   |
+--------+-------------+------------+------------+
|   9144 |         224 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-12-27 |
| 352580 |         341 | 2015-12-01 | 2016-02-06 |
|   7519 |         224 | 2015-12-27 | 2016-01-05 |
|   9141 |         224 | 2016-01-05 | 2016-02-04 |
|  13834 |         341 | 2016-01-16 | 2016-01-23 |
|   9142 |         224 | 2016-02-05 | 2016-03-04 |
| 352581 |         341 | 2016-02-07 | 2016-03-12 |
|  11707 |         341 | 2016-02-22 | 2016-03-12 |
|  11239 |         224 | 2016-03-11 | 2016-03-19 |
|  11889 |         224 | 2016-03-20 | 2016-04-03 |
| 352582 |         341 | 2016-03-27 | 2016-04-07 |
+--------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Would return:

```
+------------+------------+
| checkin    | checkout   |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-11-04 | 2016-03-19 |
| 2016-03-20 | 2016-04-07 |
+------------+------------+
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The two inner queries determine the checkin and checkout dates for each set of date ranges (there are 2 in your sample data set above).  I join these two sets of dates together and the outer query obtains the checkin/checkout date combinations which you want.

```
SELECT t2.checkin, MIN(t1.checkout) FROM
(
    SELECT b1.checkout AS checkout
    FROM bookings b1 INNER JOIN bookings b2 ON b1.checkout BETWEEN b2.checkin AND b2.checkout
    GROUP BY b1.checkout
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT b1.checkin AS checkin
    FROM bookings b1 INNER JOIN bookings b2 ON b1.checkin BETWEEN b2.checkin AND b2.checkout
    GROUP BY b1.checkout
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t2
ON t2.checkin < t1.checkout
GROUP BY t2.checkin
```

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb1ac/9)

Comment: @MarkGoldberg Make sure you test all edge cases in production.  Come back here if there any quirks.  For now, my query looks correct.

Comment: I have a similar table with overlapping open date spans, and this query is not working as expected. I don't fully understand the query, so I'm sure thats where the problem lies. Wish I understood this better as I don't know if it's an "edge" case situation or just a difference in the way such a table is handled because of the nuance that it is "opens" and "closes" where "opens" is an available day, and "closes" is an unavailable day" - which is reverse of how "checkin" and "checkout" operate.

Comment: The problem could also be with the way your data is structured in the other table.  Could you post a new question with this data and then ping me?  SQL queries are generally not one size fits all.

Comment: Looks like this isn't working properly on another set of data here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082441/mysql-consolodating-table-rows-with-overlapping-date-spans