# MySQL consolodating table rows with overlapping date spans

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a temporary table with overlapping available dates. These dates can be overlapping in any combination of ways, as they are for multiple available rooms.

I would like to create a query that returns a consolidated set of available dates. (The opens date is an available day; closes is unavailable.)

For example, the following data

```
+------------+------------+
|   opens    |   closes   |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-12-03 | 2015-12-05 |
| 2016-01-08 | 2016-01-15 |
| 2016-02-21 | 2016-02-27 |
| 2016-03-13 | 2016-03-24 |
| 2016-03-31 | 2016-04-02 |
| 2016-04-06 | 2016-04-15 |
| 2016-04-21 | 2016-12-03 |
| 2015-12-03 | 2015-12-09 |
| 2016-01-03 | 2016-01-06 |
| 2016-01-16 | 2016-02-08 |
| 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-06 |
| 2016-03-10 | 2016-12-03 |
+------------+------------+
```

Should return:

```
+------------+------------+
|   opens    |   closes   |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-12-03 | 2015-12-09 |
| 2016-01-03 | 2016-01-06 |
| 2016-01-08 | 2016-01-15 |
| 2016-01-16 | 2016-02-08 |
| 2016-02-21 | 2016-02-27 |
| 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-06 |
| 2016-03-10 | 2016-12-03 |
+------------+------------+
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Giorgos is one of the best SQL guys on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is by the use of correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       (SELECT MIN(opens)
       FROM mytable AS t2
       WHERE t2.opens <= t1.closes AND t2.closes >= t1.opens) AS start,
       (SELECT MAX(closes)
       FROM mytable AS t2
       WHERE t2.opens <= t1.closes AND t2.closes >= t1.opens) AS end       
FROM mytable AS t1
ORDER BY opens
```

The `WHERE` predicates of the correlated subqueries:

`t2.opens <= t1.closes AND t2.closes >= t1.opens`

return all overlapping records related to the current record. Performing aggregation one these records we can find the start / end dates of each interval: the start date of the interval is the minimum `opens` date between all overlapping records, whereas the end date is the maximum `closes` date.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fa44/8)

**EDIT:**

The above solution won't work with a set of intervals like the following:

```
1. |-----------|
2. |----|
3.           |-----|
```

Record no. 2, when processed, will produce a flawed start/end interval.

Here's a solution using variables:

```
SELECT MIN(start) AS start, MAX(end) AS end
FROM (
  SELECT @grp := IF(@start = '1900-01-01' OR 
                   (opens <= @end AND closes >= @start), @grp, @grp+1) AS grp,        
         @start := IF(@start = '1900-01-01', opens, 
                      IF(opens <= @end AND closes >= @start, 
                         IF (@start < opens, @start, opens), opens)) AS start,
         @end := IF(@end = '1900-01-01', closes, 
                    IF (opens <= @end AND closes >= @start, 
                      IF (@end > closes, @end, closes), closes)) AS end                 
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 1, @start := '1900-01-01', @end := '1900-01-01') AS vars
  ORDER BY opens, DATEDIFF(closes, opens) DESC) AS t
GROUP BY grp
```

The idea is to start from left-most `opens/closes` interval. Variables `@start`, `@end` are used to propagate the incrementally expanding  (as new overlapping rows are being processed) consolidated interval down the interval chain. Once a non-overlapping interval is encountered, `[@start - @end]` is initialized so as to match this new interval and `grp` is incremented by one.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fa44/31)

Comment: @Mark Giorgos' query should work just fine on your data set.  Just change the column/table names as appropriate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It turns out my query is flawed. It won't work on any combination of overlapping date intervals. For example it doesn't work with the sample data of the question asked yesterday by Mark.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos This is ironic, because my query for his previous data set appears to be working with that data set, but it does not work with the data from this problem.  Yes, the overlapping date intervals are nasty.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is due to the high irregularity of input data. A generic solution, handling all possible cases, is bound to be a lot more complicated than the above query I guess!

Comment: Just a thought, maybe querying out the troublesome overlapping records might be on the right track.

Comment: So I unchecked it as the right answer. I've struggled with this for a while. Will keep struggling today - any help would really be appreciated, as my skills are not even close to the two of you, and I've literally worked on this for days now! Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: I've come up with an alternative solution that should work with any set of input data. It actually [works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2902f2/6) with the data of your other question.